# CI 2.0 controller/function access not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I am building a website using CI, and I want my website URI to be clean as

```
http://myweb.com/controller/function
```

without 'index.php' part.

I have succeed in doing this with CI 1.73, but i can't get it working with CI 2.0 
I have set route.php to be:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

and config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

i also have put the .htaccess file that was working in my trial using CI 1.73

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myweb

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Remember to say what you are trying and what actually happened, not just "doesnt work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this line `RewriteBase /myweb` is the culprit. Try putting `RewriteBase /` instead.

Also, I would try simplifying your .htaccess at the maximum until you get it to work, something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that I think you should put just a `/` after index.php, not `?/` like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```